# How to set the selectedItem of a listpicker using databinding MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a listpicker on my Category details page

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ListPickerCategoryTypes"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Category Types;" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" Margin="9,6,0,0"  SelectedItem="{Binding CategoryTypeName, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTypeName}"  Tag="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>


            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

The list picker populates correctly but when I navigate to the details page the selectedItem is never set?

I have a category Name textbox that is correctly displaying the category name that was selected so I know it has the data just not sure what I am doing wrong 
with the listpicker. I thought maybe it was that I wasnt using the CategoryTypeName I was trying to use the Category Type ID that is on my model.

I am using MVVM so I would like to be able to do this in my view model.

Addtional Code to help
The SettingProduct view lists all the products I have in a listbox.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="TileList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileProductDataTemplate}" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayProducts}" 
                         Margin="6,20,6,-8" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditDetailsPageCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

on the tap of a product  the event command executes...

```
    this.EditDetailsPageCommand = new RelayCommand(this.GotoEditProductDetail, this.CanGotoEditProductDetail);

 public void GotoEditProductDetail()
        {


            //Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateToPageMessage>(new NavigateToPageMessage() { PageName = "SettingsProductDetail", SendObject = DisplayProducts });

           // Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateToPageMessage>(new NavigateToPageMessage(){PageName = "SettingsProductDetail", SendObject =  SelectedProduct});   
            Navigator.NavigateTo("SettingsProductDetail", SelectedProduct);
        }
```

It navigates to teh SettingsProductDetail View and in the constructor it errors on this line when setting the DataContext

SettingsProductDetail Xaml

```
<toolkit:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ListPickerCategoryTypes"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryTypes}"
                               Header="Product Types;" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" Margin="9,6,0,0" 
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoryType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               >
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTypeName}" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>


            </toolkit:ListPicker>
public SettingsProductDetail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel.SettingsProductDetailViewModel(Navigator.Object);


        }
```

In my viewmodel for the SettingsProductDetail 
I have two properties one for teh Itemsource and one for the selectedItem

```
public ObservableCollection<CategoryType> CategoryTypes
        {
            get { return _categoryType; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _categoryType)
                {
                    _categoryType = value;
                    base.RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryType");
                }
            }
        }

        public Model.CategoryType SelectedCategoryType
        {
            get { return _selectedCategoryType; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedCategoryType)
                {
                    _selectedCategoryType = value;
                    base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryType");
                }
            }
        }
```

In the construct is where I am populating the SelectedCategoryType from the object passed from the product view.

```
 public SettingsProductDetailViewModel(object sendObject)
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            }
            else
            {
                ProductDetail = sendObject as DisplayProducts;

                if (ProductDetail == null)
                {
                    ProductDetail = new DisplayProducts();
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedCategoryType = new CategoryType();
                    SelectedCategoryType.Id = ProductDetail.FkCategoryTypeID;
                    SelectedCategoryType.CategoryTypeName = ProductDetail.CategoryTypeName;
                }

                _TheStoreDataContext = new TheStoreDataContext(ConnectionString);
                PopulateHelperObjects();
                SettingsProductDetailSaveCommand = new RelayCommand<Model.Product>(param => SaveRecord(), param => (ProductDetail != null));
                SettingsProductDetailCancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelRecord, () => true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ViewModel needs to have a property called `CategoryTypeSelected` which will be of the type T, where T is the type of objects that are in the collection `CategoryTypes` which you used to bind your ItemsSource. This way, the CategoryTypeSelected will always be the item selected from the list. You bind it like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ListPickerCategoryTypes"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" ......
                    SelectedItem="{Binding CategoryTypeSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Of course, your ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I will have to see if I can do that I am passing an object of Type productDetail over that is basically the product that is selected off the product list picker.  I am guessing before I pass over the object I also need to populate a CategoryTypeSelected  of Type category in order for it to bind to that. I may be doing this incorrectly since I am binding to properties that are located in my model.I am going to have to take a look again.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I modified my view model and I added the property  with the notify  property changed but I am getting the error SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value.

Comment: Could you share a bit more code with us in your question? Important parts of viewmodel and the model class which you're binding...?

Comment: ok the error I am getting is SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value on the setting of the datacontext on the SettingsProductDetail view. I am going to add the additional code to the main question to hard to do in a comment

Comment: I got it.  I will revise my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I now have it working...

```
//It was my constructor and how I was setting the property. changed the constructor to this... if (ProductDetail == null)
                {
                    ProductDetail = new DisplayProducts();
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedCategoryType = new CategoryType {CategoryTypeName = ProductDetail.CategoryTypeName};
                    //SelectedCategoryType.Id = ProductDetail.FkCategoryTypeID;
                }
```

//  and then changed the property setter to this...  set
                {

```
                if (_categoryType.Contains(value))
                {
                    _selectedCategoryType = value;
                    base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryType");
                }
                else
                {
                    _selectedCategoryType = _categoryType.FirstOrDefault((o) => o.CategoryTypeName == value.CategoryTypeName);
                    base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryType");
                }


                //if (value != _selectedCategoryType)
                //{
                //    _selectedCategoryType = value;
                //    base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryType");
                //}
            }
```